# how to get JSON Results placed on Google Maps?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, google-maps, jsonresult

I have my JSON Results shown below that i have pulled out of my database, Iwant to display this on google maps using a marker which is displayed based on the position here are the results;

```js
{
    "user": [{
        "name" : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "posn" : [53.491314, -2.249451]
    }, {
        "name" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "posn" : [54.949231, -1.620483]
    }]
}
```

How do i get the user name and position placed on google maps? Coding for my googlemaps below;

```html
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:600px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/markermanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/google_northamerica_offices.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mgr;

        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180);
                    bounds.extend(latlng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // animation disabled because it slows down performance
                        title: "RedStar Creative Marker #" + i
                    });
                    mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);
                }
                mgr.refresh();

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize();
        });

    </script>
```

i've tried doing it like this, dont know if its the right way of doing it, first time using JSON;

```js
    function setupUserMarkers() {
        var markers = [];
        for (var j in layer["users"]) {
            var place = layer["users"][j];
            var title = place["name"];
            var posn = new GLatLng(place["posn"][0], place["posn"][1]);
            var marker = createMarker(posn,title); 
            markers.push(marker);
            allmarkers.push(marker);
        }
        mgr.addMarkers(markers, layer["zoom"][0], layer["zoom"][1]);
    }
    mgr.refresh();
}
```

**UPDATE:** using AJAX i was able to add the two markers based on the JSON Result, trying to figure out how to add a window popup so it will display an image of that person in the window. i know i will need an google.maps.event.addListener and the next bit well its for me to research now, hope the AJAX below will help others who come across a similiar problem to me.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetUser",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.user.length; i++) {
                            var label = data.user[i].name;
                            var lat = data.user[i].posn[0];
                            var long = data.user[i].posn[1];

                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                            bounds.extend(latlng);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng,
                                title: label
                            });
```

Comment: Is there a public URL for the JSON? If so, I can setup a demo on jsFiddle.

Comment: @Salman sorry no public link as im working on the localhost using Visual Web Dev. there is a URL for the facebook profile picture though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my JSON result i want to be able to get this image in to info window on google maps when user clicks on marker

```
image":"http://graph.facebook.com/10000090226****/picture?type=large"
```

here is part of the coding for the google maps

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mgr;

    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.491314, -2.249451),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetUser",
                context: document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.user.length; i++) {
                        var label = data.user[i].name;
                        var lat = data.user[i].posn[0];
                        var long = data.user[i].posn[1];

                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                        bounds.extend(latlng);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            title: label
                        });

                        mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);

                    }
                    //adding google maps window popup...
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }

            });

            mgr.refresh();

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        initialize();
    });

    </script>
```

at the moment its not opening a window, wont it even open if there is no content inside it? bit confused on trying to get the image inside the content window. I'll have to keep digging around and see if i can manage to get in the URL image in there.

does the adding window popup bit need to come after the refresh of the markers?

**UPDATE;** sorted the problem, was adding bits of coding in the wrong places, needed some tweaking. **whats happening now is when you click the first marker it opens the info window on the second marker and displays the name, but the first marker that was initially clicked does not open an infoWindow.**

```
function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetUser",
                context: document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.user.length; i++) {
                        var label = data.user[i].name;
                        var lat = data.user[i].posn[0];
                        var long = data.user[i].posn[1];

                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                        bounds.extend(latlng);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            title: label
                        });

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: data.user[i].name });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });

                        mgr.addMarker(marker, 1);
```

**FINAL UPDATE:** *right i can stop panicking, managed to get it working after slapping myself to wake up and read things more than 3 times :)*

Comment: Please update your question to add the details instead of posting as an answer.

Comment: never mind i got it working, i was adding the bounds.extend and info marker at the wrong places. Works fine now. Question updated

Comment: @SalmanA when I click the first marker it opens the info window on the second marker and displays the name, but the first marker that was initially clicked does not open an infoWindow.

Answer (score 1):

In the core of your above the example code is looping 10 times adding random points - you need to replace that with a loop over your points.

Specifically this bit:

```
       // loop over your points
           for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // use your points lat/lng
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180);
                bounds.extend(latlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // animation disabled because it slows down performance
                    // use your points name
                    title: "RedStar Creative Marker #" + i
                });
                mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);
            }
```

Here is an untested first go, no guarantees, blah blah blah :)

```
       // loop over your points
       for (var j in layer["users"]) {
                var place = layer["users"][j];
                // use your points lat/lng
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(place["posn"][0], place["posn"][1]);
                bounds.extend(latlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // animation disabled because it slows down performance
                    // use your points name
                    title: place["name"]
                });
                mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);
            }
```

Comment: i used AJAX and it does the job for me, shows the marker for 2 users based on the JSON created. But for some reason the map is being loaded to just outside Australia.. Hmmm will need to sort that out next, thanks Chris

Comment: you can have a look at the AJAX i did to place two markers on the map based on the position from the JSON, Quite impressed with myself, but without the help of you and others here i wouldnt be able to learn quickly enough :)